# Facebook push campaigns (Beta) not working

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, facebook-analytics

I wanted to try out the new push campaigns by facebook analytics for our android app.
I have done the following:

1) added the dependencies to my gradle file:

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.+'
```

2) Set the API key for android on facebook analytics settings page
3) Set the registration Id for on the client using the line:

```
    AppEventsLogger.setPushNotificationsRegistrationId(registration);
```

For testing this I created a build with an incremented version id, and set up a segment for that version id (with an event). I Installed the build on a few phones, and it took hours for the segment to get updated

The reach for the segment is shown as 2 users.

But, when I run a push campaign on that segment, the result is always 0 delivered and 0 opened. I don't get any GCM messages in my service at all.

I have tested the implementation using the option given on the analytics settings page using the API key and device token - it works fine, and GCM messages are sent to the particular device with that token.

However, when I run a campaign using a segment, nothing happens; no notifications are sent - even though the segment reach shown is of 2 users.

Why is this so? Is there a bug in the facebook platform, or did I miss out on any integration step?

Comment: Just tested the tool mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/quickstart and no notifications are coming through Android.

Comment: Any update on your issue? I am getting the same results.

Comment: Unfortunately no. We decided to chuck it, and are currently using mixpanel and hotline for push notifications.

Comment: I am facing same problem in iOS too.